# Eclipse uses wrong java home

Tags: java, eclipse, windows

I'm using Eclipse on Windows and I don't understand why it's using a specific java version. I can check the java version using by Eclipse doing this *Help -> About Eclipse -> Installation Details -> Configuration*. The **java.home** is set to *C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_65*. But my *environment variables* are configured like this :

- JAVA_7_HOME : C:\java\jdk1.7.0_79
- JAVA_8_HOME : C:\java\jdk1.8.0_60
- JAVA_HOME : %JAVA_8_HOME%
- PATH : ...;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;...;

Why Eclipse is not using *C:\java\jdk1.8.0_60* as **java.home**.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `JAVA_HOME` environment variable is not supposed to be the same the `java.home` system property. `JAVA_HOME` is an OS-level environment setting, while `java.home` is a Java-level property that's established by the JVM when it starts; it indicates the root (home) of the JRE that is *currently running* (which very well might be different than where you pointed `JAVA_HOME` to).

The reason you're not getting the value for `java.home` that you expect is probably because you have not specified to Eclipse what JVM you want it to run in (which is separate from the **Installed JREs** you see in the Preferences). Follow the [instructions for specifying the JVM in `eclipse.ini`](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini), point it to the JDK location you want (`C:\java\jdk1.8.0_60` according to your example above), then Eclipse will report that as the value of `java.home` (since that will be the JVM that's running Eclipse itself).

Answer (score 5):

You can set the default JRE for Eclipse the following way:

- Go to the global preferences
- Click `Java` -> `Installed JREs`
- You'll find a list of JREs available for Eclipse, one of which will be checked as default
- If JRE8u60 is not in the list, you can `Add...` it, then make it default

Comment: I did that before especially because I run my projects with different Java versions. But the java.home in Eclipse is always set with the wrong value. And this is problematic for Maven.

Comment: This did not work for me, @E-Riz answer worked for me